# How is BABBAB formed

Tags: mathematics, letter-sequence, sequence

$[A ...] \to A [...]$

$[B ...] \to B [S [...]]$

$[S A ...] \to B ...$

$[S B ...] \to A [S ...]$

$[S] \to B$

$[  ] \to$

(E.g. $[AAB] \to AABB$)

But, $[????] \to BABBAB$

Bonus puzzle:

> Characterize all sequences of A's and B's so that $[?] => sequence$, for some ? sequence of A's and B's

Comment: Hello! Welcome to puzzling SE! Please take the tour (you'll also get a badge, too) to get a better understanding of community expectations.

Comment: Wow is everyone overlooking that clever title ?! Made me chuckle about those decade old memes. [Obligatory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll-lia-FEIY) and related [required viewing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EShUeudtaFg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only four-letter sequence [????] that works is:

> [BBBB]

This evaluates as

> [BBBB] →
>  B[S[BBB]] →
>  B[SB[S[BB]]] →
>  B[SB[SB[S[B]]]] →
>  B[SB[SB[SB[S[]]]]] →
>  B[SB[SB[SB[S]]]] →
>  B[SB[SB[SBB]]] →
>  B[SB[SBA[SB]]] →
>  B[SB[SBAA[S]]] →
>  B[SB[SBAAB]] →
>  B[SBA[SAAB]] →
>  B[SBABAB] →
>  BA[SABAB] →

BABBAB

I found this through directed guessing:

> I evaluated the 3 letter sequences [AAB], [BBA] and [BBB], and these gave me a good feel for what might work and what definitely wouldn't. Then I jumped to four letter sequences and took a couple wrong guesses before finding this solution.

---

Bonus:
I've now written some code to find generable outputs (and was able to confirm that the above solution is unique for four letter inputs).  I believe that the rule is:

> Treating "A" as 0 and "B" as 1, and evaluating the outputs that can be produced by this ruleset as binary, the possible outputs are all the multiples of 3.  (Or, at minimum, they are all multiples of 3, even if not all such multiples can be generated.)

Here's what I've been able to find are the generable outputs:

> length of 1:  **A** *B*
>  length of 2:  **AA** *AB* *BA* **BB**
>  length of 3:  **AAA** *AAB* *ABA* **ABB** *BAA* *BAB* **BBA** *BBB*
>  length of 4: **AAAA** *AAAB* *AABA* **AABB** *ABAA* *ABAB* **ABBA** *ABBB*
>           *BAAA* **BAAB** *BABA* *BABB* **BBAA** *BBAB* *BBBA* **BBBB**
>  where **BOLD** are generable outputs and *ITALIC* are outputs that cannot be generated.
>
>  The only generable outputs of length 5 are:
>          **AAAAA AAABB AABBA ABAAB ABBAA ABBBB**
>          **BAABA BABAB BBAAA BBABB BBBBA**
>
>  and for length 6 are:
>          **AAAAAA AAAABB AAABBA AABAAB AABBAA AABBBB**
>          **ABAABA ABABAB ABBAAA ABBABB ABBBBA BAAAAB**
>          **BAABAA BAABBB BABABA BABBAB BBAAAA BBAABB**
>          **BBABBA BBBAAB BBBBAA BBBBBB**

I finally noticed that ...

> the generable outputs occur at intervals of 3.

Comment: the bonus question is asking for a general rule of [?] where ? can represent any string of As and Bs

Comment: The bonus question asks which sequences its possible to end up with given a start of A's and B's (there is a very simple rule to tell if a sequence is a possible output)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its a typo or not, but currently from the list of rules

> [SAABBAB]= BABBAB

Comment: Was thinking about the same

Comment: I assumed "[????]" was seeking a four letter sequence.  If not then yes, this is correct.

Comment: maybe OP meant [SA....]=B[...] and just typoed?

Comment: @Rubio Either that or, from the way the bonus is phrased, ???? can only contain A's and B's, without any S's.

Comment: I found a four letter sequence. Finally. So this may be academic anyway. :)

Comment: @Rubio out of curiosity how did u solve it?

Comment: Yes, I intended ???? to mean 4 characters

Comment: Directed guessing.  I tried 3 letter sequences [AAB],  [BBA] and [BBB] and they gave me a good feel for what might work and what definitely wouldn't.  Then jumped to four letter sequences and took a couple wrong guesses before finding that one.